Handshaking not happening between client and server
I am trying a DTLS communication between server and client using python3-dtls. Below are the server code and client code. Once the server is set to listen(), it starts the handshaking procedure but it is stuck there afterwards and handshaking also is not completed.
i am trying to understand the possible reason for that.
server code:
import socket
from os import path
from logging import basicConfig, DEBUG
basicConfig(level=DEBUG)  # set now for dtls import code
from dtls.sslconnection import SSLConnection
from dtls.err import SSLError, SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN


def main():
    cert_path = path.join(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)), "certs")
        sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sck.bind(("127.0.0.1", 28000))
    sck.setblocking(False)
    sck.settimeout(30)

    scn = SSLConnection(
        sck,
        keyfile=path.join(cert_path, "keycert.pem"),
        certfile=path.join(cert_path, "keycert.pem"),
        server_side=True,
        ca_certs=path.join(cert_path, "ca-cert.pem"),
        do_handshake_on_connect=True)

    cnt = 0
    while True:
        cnt += 1
        print("Listen invocation: %d" % cnt)
        peer_address = scn.listen()
        print(f"peer_address: {peer_address}")
        if peer_address:
            print("Completed listening for peer: %s" % str(peer_address))
            break

    print("Accepting...")
    conn = scn.accept()[0]
    sck.settimeout(5)
    conn.get_socket(True).settimeout(5)

    cnt = 0
    while True:
        cnt += 1
        # print("Listen invocation: %d" % cnt)
        # peer_address = scn.listen()
        # assert not peer_address
        print("Handshake invocation: %d" % cnt)
        try:
            conn.do_handshake()
        except SSLError as err:
            if err.errno == 504:
                continue
            raise
        print("Completed handshaking with peer")
        break

    cnt = 0
    while True:
        cnt += 1
        # print("Listen invocation: %d" % cnt)
        # peer_address = scn.listen()
        # assert not peer_address
        print("Read invocation: %d" % cnt)
        try:
            message = conn.read()
        except SSLError as err:
            if err.errno == 502:
                continue
            if err.args[0] == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                break
            raise
        print(message.decode())
        conn.write(str("Back to you: " + message.decode()).encode())

    cnt = 0
    while True:
        cnt += 1
        # print("Listen invocation: %d" % cnt)
        # peer_address = scn.listen()
        # assert not peer_address
        print("Shutdown invocation: %d" % cnt)
        try:
            s = conn.unwrap()
            s.close()
        except SSLError as err:
            if err.errno == 502:
                continue
            raise
        break

    sck.close()

    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Client code:
from os import path
import ssl
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
from logging import basicConfig, DEBUG
basicConfig(level=DEBUG)  # set now for dtls import code
from dtls import do_patch
do_patch()

cert_path = path.join(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)), "certs")
s = ssl.wrap_socket(socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM), cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, ca_certs=path.join(cert_path, "ca-cert.pem"))
#s.setblocking(False)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 28000))
s.send('Hi there'.encode())
print(s.recv().decode())
s = s.unwrap()
s.close()

pass

